# Map DataFrame columns

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm pretty new to Python and trying to transform data from a tab separated file into json using Azure Databricks. I have the following input data:

```
ID  Title   NumberA NumberB
1   test1   0       1
2   test2   2       3
```

and I'm trying to transform it into json of the form:

```json
[
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "Title": "title1",
        "Numbers": [
            {
                "Type": "TypeA",
                "Code": "0"
            },
            {
                "Type": "TypeB",
                "Code": "1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "ID": 2,
        "Title": "title2",
        "Numbers": [
            {
                "Type": "TypeA",
                "Code": "2"
            },
            {
                "Type": "TypeB",
                "Code": "3"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have a schema like this for my input data:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType

class MySchemas:
    def input_struct():
        schema = StructType()
        schema.add('ID', IntegerType(), True)
        schema.add('Title', StringType(), True)
        schema.add('NumberA', IntegerType(), True)
        schema.add('NumberB', IntegerType(), True)
        schema.add('_corrupt_record', StringType(), True)
        return schema
```

In another class, I'm reading the input data using the schema as follows:

```
df_schema = MySchemas.input_struct()
inputs = self.spark.read.option('sep', "\t").option("header","true").option('mode', 'PERMISSIVE').schema(df_schema).csv(self.sourceFilePath, quote="", escape="")
```

I have no idea how do the last part. I need to take `NumberA` and `NumberB` columns and replace them with a single column called `Numbers` which is a list of objects with a literal string column called `Type` and another column containing the values from `NumberA` and `NumberB`.

Can someone tell me how to do this please? I'm using Databricks Runtime 5.5 LTS with Spark 2.4.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create array of structs and convert to json:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

result = inputs.select(
    'ID', 'Title', 
    F.array(
        F.struct(
            F.lit('TypeA').alias('Type'), 
            F.col('NumberA').alias('Code')
        ), 
        F.struct(
            F.lit('TypeB').alias('Type'), 
            F.col('NumberB').alias('Code')
        )
    ).alias('Numbers')
).agg(
    F.collect_list(
        F.to_json(F.struct('ID', 'Title', 'Numbers'))
    ).alias('col')
)

result.show(truncate=False)
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|col                                                                                                                                                                                 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[{"ID":1,"Title":"test1","Numbers":[{"Type":"TypeA","Code":0},{"Type":"TypeB","Code":1}]}, {"ID":2,"Title":"test2","Numbers":[{"Type":"TypeA","Code":2},{"Type":"TypeB","Code":3}]}]|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If you want to output JSON file instead, you can skip the `.agg` part, and do `result.write.json('filepath')`.